# How to import a space-separated file with spaces-filled columns and variable number of spaces between them

Tags: r, import

I am sorry for the title of the post, it is a bit tricky to phrase it.

I have a set of files that I struggle to import into R because even though the files look like fixed-width, they actually have slightly variable number of characters in each column, and spaces are used both as separators and as "filler" in otherwise empty cells.

The files come from a '90s program to characterise codon usage in sequence data ([CodonW](https://codonw.sourceforge.net/) Because I cannot easily import them, below is a screenshot of what they look like, with spaces highlighted.

EDIT: I have uploaded a test file to Dropbox if you want to play with it: [stacktest.blk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcq055bvw3fo2ay/stacktest.blk?dl=1)

[image: CodonW output screenshot]

EDIT2: As @G below noted, the read.fwf code below will import this file with no issues, so here is another output that this code will not import  correctly due to different numbers of characters/spaces in various columns.

[stacktest_alt.blk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r31euqbrbnslx47/stacktest_alt.blk?dl=1)

The problem is that as the numbers get bigger, the number of spaces separating the numeric columns change, and I cannot then invoke the set number of characters delineating the columns on import with `read.fwf()`, e.g.

```
read.fwf(my_file, widths = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5))
```

What is the best approach to import this file? I am starting to think that it needs something like "import first row to determine number of columns and then fit the remaining rows into this number of columns using spaces as separators". But then the new issue is with the column under the "Ser" (and others like it), because only the first row has space separators between the columns, the other rows *also* use spaces to fill in the column itself.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `read.table` work? The docs say by default for `read.table` "the separator is ‘white space’, that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage returns

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note in particular that it asks not to use images for input since others don't want to have to retype it all. to test their code. Use text that can easily be copied and pasted.

Comment: In the example you posted, it doesn't seem that the width of the columns change at all.  I'm not sure why you'd be having trouble with fixed width fields in that case. If you don't know the widths, then yes, reading part of the file to guess where they are would make sense.

Comment: @nniloc No, read.table doesn't work, the problem is already in the second row, column below "Ser". read.table doesn't realise that everything under "Ser" should be a column, instead it collapses the all the filler spaces.

Comment: @G I am sorry but I could not write a reproducible code example. If I knew how to do it in this case, asking the question would become moot :-) But I have uploaded the file from the screenshot to Dropbox.

Comment: @MrFlick They do change. Imagine the number next to UUU is a 5-digit instead of 3-digit one. The number of spaces between the columns then change as the software adjusts the output so it looks like a "proper" table.

Comment: If the blank lines and junk at the end is removed then the read.fwf in the question works with the file provided.

Comment: @G Yes, I know, but this solution breaks when the number of digits of numbers in the columns changes. I am looking for an answer that would work without me counting the number of spaces first.